# How can I take a dump file for Winforms application

Tags: c#, dump, crash-dumps

I have a C# application which is crashing for unknown reason.

For understanding the issue, i want to take a dump file for it.

How can i do it?

many thanks,

Oz.

Comment: Why just don't debug your application so you can easily lookup the execution path and variables

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about taking a minidump when your application crashes so you can debug it with windbg or cdb ?

If yes, there are different approaches:

**DrWatson**
    -Run `drwtsn32 -i` at the commandprompt, this will activate dr watson and let it listen in the background for all crashes.

**Windbg**
    -Run `windbg -I` from the commandpromt starting from the installation folder of Windbg.
    -When a crash occurs, windbg will immediately load the crash dump.

Make sure you download and install the [Debugging tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) first.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows Vista/7 or Server 2008, then you can open Task Manager and manually create a dump file, as explained [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/window-on-windows/?p=459). I would recommend using Windbg for catching the crash, as Mez suggested, since then you can perform immediate crash dump analysis on the process.

Answer (score -1):

You must catch the exception and output it to a log file in your main.

i.e.,

```
static int main()
{
  try
  {
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    WriteToLogFile(ex);
  }
}
```

Comment: He asked for a dump file. If you want to be notified about exceptions, AppDomain.UnhandledException is a better choice.