# Any way to create a heap dump/histogram on OutOfMemoryException in C#?

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, heap-dump

Back in the Java world I was able to specify that the JVM should create a heap dump file on the first OutOfMemoryError.  Is there anything equivalent in C#?

A heap dump would be ideal but I'd settle for a histogram.

If there's no way to do this automatically is there a way to hook this exception and then walk the heap manually?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123021/how-to-create-process-mini-dump-on-crash-without-running-adplus-explicitly-on-wi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721111/how-can-i-take-a-dump-file-for-winforms-application

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MS Debugging tools ADPlus utility to get a process dump that includes the all the heaps.
Then using WinDBG.exe (also in debugging tools) you can use the !DumpHeap command to get all the data you need.

[a little old but useful HOWTO link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx)

Comment: Thanks @Menahem, good suggestion, however I'd really like something that can record the output on users' machines, I won't be able to attach a debugger at the time.

Comment: @chillitom in that case you can configure the debugger to take the dump silently on the clients machine , automatically when it happens. then copy the dump to a machine where you can analyse it. Mitch Wheat posted a link to a description of how to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [procdump](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900) because you can easily set it up before the crash to dump out the memory when the crash occurs.  Then use windbg to look through the memory.

I would add that if it is not immediately obvious where the memory is going (using sos.dll tools command [!dumpheap -stat](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks.aspx)), then you can use procdump to take a number of crash dumps at particular intervals so that you can track what memory is growing.

If you are not familiar with windbg and sos, you might want to [check this out](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/03/11/where-s-your-leak-at-using-windbg-sos-and-gcroot-to-diagnose-a-net-memory-leak.aspx).